# How to set Vscode Commit Messages AI Provider

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-commit, github-copilot

I'm using Github Copilot and Genie (ChatGPT) as AI providers extentions in Vscode.
I would like to change the defualt AI provider for commit messages from Genie to Copilot, From the Lightning icon to the Copilot Sparkles icon.

[image]

[image]

Couldn't find the settings to change that

Comment: what version of the GitHub Copilot extension are you using? see the bottom of my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77594965/11107541.

Answer (score 0):

This is provided via Gitlens extension. It's not normally available with VSCode. To find all the settings related to AI commits do the following:

1. Open User Settings (can use command pallete and type user settings)
2. Scroll down to GitLens and expand the drop down
3. Scroll down to AI and select
4. You can now change all settings related to AI messages

Comment: the asker did not list gitlens as an extension they are using. they listed copilot and genie

Comment: Genie doesn't make commits to github in vscode. It can write the messages though. Those sparkles are what I've seen with gitlens. I had gitlens prompt me for an ai engine to write commit messages. I picked the wrong one and had to dig through settings to find how to change it like OP is asking. So I am sharing my experience with the sparkles that were in the screenshot. It is possible that he has gitlens and didn't make the connection. I have never seen the lightning bolt and that does look like a genie feature.