# How do I create a custom button in the git Message field of the VS Code Source Control tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-git

I am creating a VS Code extension. I want to add a custom button to the Git message field of the VS Code Source Control tab?

To be specific location, please see the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to add a custom button to this location. Just like GitHub Copilot did.

So my question are:

1. How to add button to it?
2. How can I put generated message to the "Message" field?

Comment: how does GitHub Copilot doe this, examine the source of the extension

Comment: @rioV8 The GitHub Copilot extension has been minified and very hard to read.

Comment: if it adds a button it most likely has to do it from `package.json` that is not minified, and you can search the code for `Generate Commit Message`

Comment: @rioV8 YES, you are right. I found it. Thanks! It's `scm/inputBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [the `contribSourceControlInputBoxMenu` API proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.contribSourceControlInputBoxMenu.d.ts). See also its issue ticket: [SourceControl - SourceControlInputBoxValueProvider API proposal #195474](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195474).

The API proposal is current empty. At a previous point in time, it looked like this:

> ```js
> /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  *  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>  *  Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
>  *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
>
> declare module 'vscode' {
>   // https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195474
>
>   export namespace scm {
>       export function registerSourceControlInputBoxValueProvider(sourceControlId: string, provider: SourceControlInputBoxValueProvider): Disposable;
>   }
>
>   export interface SourceControlInputBoxValueProviderContext {
>       readonly resourceGroupId: string;
>       readonly resources: readonly Uri[];
>   }
>
>   export interface SourceControlInputBoxValueProvider {
>       readonly label: string;
>       readonly icon?: Uri | { light: Uri; dark: Uri } | ThemeIcon;
>
>       provideValue(rootUri: Uri, context: SourceControlInputBoxValueProviderContext[], token: CancellationToken): ProviderResult<string | undefined>;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

You could take a look at [the GitHub Copilot Chat extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot-chat)'s minified code as an example (download VSIX, rename filename extension to ".zip", unzip). In its extension manifest, it has this:

> ```json
> "scm/inputBox": [
>   {
>     "command": "github.copilot.git.generateCommitMessage",
>     "when": "scmProvider == git"
>   }
> ]
> ```

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api.

When the API still existed, the way to change the value of the input box was `vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.git')?.exports.getAPI(1).repositories[0].inputBox.value = newvalue;`.

Note that later versions of GitHub Copilot started using the `scminput` language instead of the `scm/inputbox` menu contribution point (see the `github.copilot.enable` setting).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. But I still can't figure out how to set new value to the inputBox of the scm?

Comment: I found it. `vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.git')?.exports.getAPI(1).repositories[0].inputBox.value = newvalue;`

Comment: The `contribSourceControlInputBoxMenu` seems only exists in VSCode v1.85+, right?

Comment: It's still a Proposed API. I get it.