# How to show the lightning icon in vscode extension ChatGPT Genie AI

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like AI to generate commit message and installed vscode extension ChatGPT Genie AI. But I can't find the lightning icon in Source Control in vscode.
What am i missing? Any suggestion will be great help. Thank you.

Lightning icon missing:

[image: Lightning icon missing]

It should be like this:

[image: It should be like this.]

I couldn't find the settings for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/77595771/11107541. TL;DR I don't think the API that enabled what you're looking for exists anymore. And even when it existed, it was only experimental. At the time of this writing (version 0.0.10 of the Genie extension), it does provide a button in the SCM title menu contribution point (see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider#menus), which is to the right of the SCM view title that can be used to generate a commit message, and you can use the command that button invokes directly: `Genie: Generate a commit message`, or bind it to a keybinding using its ID, `chatgpt-vscode.generateCommitMessage`.